# Graph API for getting a facebook pages upcoming events?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to check weekly, if any new events have been created by some Facebook pages. Since we are not allowed to scrape / OCR, I thought I would try the graph API they provide.
However, I cannot figure out how I can check the upcoming events held by a page.
I have tried the approach mentioned in other posts, but  to avail

```
GET /v19.0/page_id/events
```

This just gives me

```
==== Response
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '61556110356590' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "AwWTnjeCMxQpcVqUOlYojft"
    },
    "__debug__": {}
  }
```

Comment: You don't get access to pages you don't have admin access to any more, unless your app has the [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access/) feature approved. (And even then I am not sure if you can access events.)